# AND clause for matching 3 conditions in NEO4j

Tags: neo4j

my query is :

```
MATCH (n:TemplateForm)-[r:DEFINED_BY]-(m:ProjectForm)-[s:CONNECTED]-(b:ProjectPage)-[p:CONNECTED]-(d:ProjectField) 
WHERE Id(n) = 907318 
  AND b.name = "REPORT PHOTOS - COVER AND APPENDICES" 
  AND NOT (d.type IN (['imageArray','image','barSeparator','map'])) 
  AND (d.name) IN(["Photo 5 Description:"]) 
  AND (d.value) IN (["penthouse roof"]) 
RETURN d
```

i have 3 fields- Photo 6 Description:", "Photo 7 Description:" ,"Photo 5 Description: in d.name
i give 3 values to them in d.value  - penthouse roof" ,"House" ,"farmhouse"
now i get result as - wherever the values get matched i get all rows. if in Photo 7 Description i have penthouse still i get it as result what i want is if only in Photo 6 Description i have penthouse ,in Photo 7 Description i have house and in Photo 5 Description i have farmhouse then only this should get satisfied

Comment: Hi! What's the issue here? What's your expected result vs what's the actual result?

Comment: MATCH (n:TemplateForm)-[r:DEFINED_BY]-(m:ProjectForm)-[s:CONNECTED]-(b:ProjectPage)-[p:CONNECTED]-(d:ProjectField) Where Id(n) = 907318 AND b.name = "REPORT PHOTOS - COVER AND APPENDICES" AND NOT (d.type IN (['imageArray','image','barSeparator','map'])) AND (d.name) IN(["Photo 6 Description:", "Photo 7 Description:","Photo 5 Description:"]) AND (d.value) IN (["penthouse roof","House","farmhouse"]) return d  ->

how this condition will to be written

Comment: Issue is: if i execute this query it goes in OR condition:

Comment: I find it hard to believe to be honest. The query clearly states "AND" conditions. Can you extend your question with an example of the result set you get and telling us which are the records you "don't want"?

Comment: i have 3 fields- Photo 6 Description:", "Photo 7 Description:" ,"Photo 5 Description: ok?
no i give 3 values to them - penthouse roof" ,"House" ,"farmhouse" right?
now i get result as - wherever the values get matched i get all rows.
if in Photo 7 Description i have penthouse still i get it as result
what i want is if only in Photo 6 Description i have penthouse ,in  Photo 7 Description i have house and in Photo 5 Description i have farmhouse then only this should get satisfied

Comment: You should update the question with this information so everyone can see them. There is a lack of information and it's difficult to understand your needs. Try this one MATCH (n:TemplateForm)-[r:DEFINED_BY]-(m:ProjectForm)-[s:CONNECTED]-(b:ProjectPage)-[p:CONNECTED]-(d:ProjectField) 
WHERE Id(n) = 907318 
  AND b.name = "REPORT PHOTOS - COVER AND APPENDICES" 
  AND NOT (d.type IN ['imageArray','image','barSeparator','map'])
  AND d.name = "Photo 5 Description:"
  AND d.value = "penthouse roof"
RETURN d

Comment: i have 3 keys in d.name

Comment: In the original question you only have one. I'm reading that one, please fix that one too. Now I understood your needs, need to figure it out

Comment: ok thank you
please help me out
i am stuck up in this since 3 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want all the `:projectFields` nodes that have the following criteria:

- name = "Photo 5 Description:" and value = "farmhouse"
- name = "Photo 6 Description:" and value = "penthouse roof"
- name = "Photo 7 Description:" and value = "house"

or something like that. All the other conditions that seems to be working.

I'm concerned about the modelling of your domain, but since it's not your question I'll leave my considerations for me.

I would try something like this:

```
MATCH (n:TemplateForm)-[r:DEFINED_BY]-(m:ProjectForm)-[s:CONNECTED]-(b:ProjectPage)-[p:CONNECTED]-(d:ProjectField) 
WHERE Id(n) = 907318 
    AND b.name = "REPORT PHOTOS - COVER AND APPENDICES" 
    AND NOT (d.type IN ['imageArray','image','barSeparator','map']) 
    AND (
        (d.name = "Photo 6 Description:" AND d.value = "penthouse roof") 
        OR (d.name = "Photo 7 Description:" AND d.value = "house")
        OR (d.name = "Photo 5 Description:" AND d.value = "farmhouse")
    )
RETURN d
```

In this way it should return all the `:projectFields` that match one of those criteria, every other combination will be excluded.

I might have understood wrong, if so I'm sorry.

One thing that I need to suggest is to add at least relationship direction to improve performances.

Comment: yes exactly this,
only 1 thing (
        (d.name = "Photo 6 Description:" AND d.value = "penthouse roof") 
        OR (d.name = "Photo 7 Description:" AND d.value = "house")
        OR (d.name = "Photo 5 Description:" AND d.value = "farmhouse")
    )--- i need AND inspite of OR
-can this be done

Comment: If you use "AND" it will search for all the 3 conditions on the same node, this is basically impossibile. Try to run that one and let me know. If you use what I provided, you it will search for all the nodes of type :projectFields and find the ones that matches one of those 3. It's impossibile that one node will have 3 different names or 3 different values. What are you searching for are 3 different nodes, each one with one of those 3 name-value combinations.

Comment: Nice, please confirm the answer if it fits your needs. Have a great weekend